# Generate unique button using for loop tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, unique

I have created a button using for loop which is successful but I cannot pass different argument to the function 
OR 
Is there any way to assign id or name to button 
And then fetch name

Answer (score -1):

I'd need a little bit more information if not but it sounds like what you want to do can be handled with callback functions. From the [effbot tkinter pages](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm):

```
def callback(number):
    print "button", number

Button(text="one",   command=callback(1)).pack()
Button(text="two",   command=callback(2)).pack()
Button(text="three", command=callback(3)).pack()
```

Rather than 1, 2, 3, simply insert whatever callback ID/information you need.

Comment: But I'm using for loop to Generate numbers